# Is PHP a secure programming language?

Tags: php, security

I keep hearing so many people get weary when I say "It was built in PHP". "Oh, PHP is so easy to hack." "PHP isn't secure". I remember a long time ago this was an issue, but I feel as the years have passed PHP has become more secure as a language? Can anyone (2018) prove me wrong?

Can someone list potential security risks associated with PHP 7?

We're developing a cryptocurrency exchange in PHP at the moment, too.

Comment: It's as insecure as people make it ... and PHP has a pretty low barrier to entry.

Comment: "PHP has a pretty low barrier to entry", can you clarify that point please :)

Comment: PHP is as insecure as you make it. PHP must often handle variables coming from GET And POST requests. It is at this point it can be insecure, but that is not due to PHP itself, but the programmers making the application. So "rule of thumb", NEVER ever trust the user input, and sanitize/verify as soon as you handle user input, don't start thinking "I'll handle it later on" when I am done with all the fun coding, as this may lead to insecure bugs.

Comment: You don't need a degree course or expensive software to start hacking around in PHP; just drop XAMPP and Netbeans on your home PC and away you go. It's quite possible to get a PHP/MySQL driven site with a login form up and running without knowing anything about security, password salting and hashing or SQL injection. It's also quite forgiving; with loosely typed variables. So it's very easy to write very bad code in PHP - that's the low barrier to entry. It's only really a bad thing if that bad code goes onto live websites.

Answer (score 2):

As some of the other answers and comments have pointed out, any language can be used to develop applications that are insecure, or are more secure than others, by means of input validation and sanitization, secure password management and other factors, depending on the scale, scope, and purpose of the application.

In terms of the underlying language itself, there are a few resources helpful to determine language and implementation vulnerabilities and how (if possible) to mitigate them.

OWASP ([Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/About_The_Open_Web_Application_Security_Project)) provides a "[cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)" on best practices for securing and developing PHP applications.

For specific vulnerabilities, you can look at [CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/) on NIST's website such as https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-5711, or [this website](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/PHP-PHP.html) that lists and details the CVEs.

Answer (score 0):

Not PHP itself is insecure, it's the apps that are created by the coders that can be insecure.

Basic PHP is very simple to learn. This is a good thing, not a bad thing. This mean that a lot of people can code in PHP, without spending too much effort on learning.

If people abuse of this characteristic to write bad code, it’s because they are bad coders.

Answer (score -2):

If you are doing coding in simple core php then it can be insecure, but if you are using any framework or using OOPS reduces insecurity and enhances security in your webapp.

Comment: While perhaps true, it doesn't capture the reason as well as other comments and answers have pointed out. Frameworks don't magically make a language secure, they simply (often) employ best practices such as input sanitization and secure directory structures, something that *can* be done without the implementation of a framework. Using the wrong framework, or the right framework in the wrong way can revert any potential advantages.